# Cant get previous url in chrome using javascript

Tags: google-chrome, url, history

In mozilla it works fine, but in chrome it doesnt return the previous url.

```
    window.history.back();
    var url=location.hash;
    console.log(url);
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: I solved it using "hashchange" jquery method. It works fine now.

Comment: Post your code....